# Calling a Django function inside an AWS Lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to defer some processing load from my Django app to an AWS Lambda.

I'm calling my code from the Lambda like this:

**lambda.py:**

```
@bc_lambda(level=logging.INFO, service=LAMBDA_SERVICE)
def task_handler(event, context):
    message = event["Records"][0]["body"]
    renderer = get_renderer_for(message)
    result = renderer.render()
    return result
```

`get_renderer_for` is a factory method that returns an instance of the class `Renderer`:

```
from myproject.apps.engine.documents import (
    DocumentsLoader,
    SourceNotFound,
    source_from_version,
)
from myproject.apps.engine.environment import Environment

class Renderer:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def render(self):
        ENVIRONMENT = Environment(DocumentsLoader())
        version_id = self.message.get("version_id")

        try:
            source = source_from_version(version_id)
        except SourceNotFound:
            source = None

        template = ENVIRONMENT.from_string(source)

        if template:
            return template.render(self.message)

        return None


def get_renderer_for(message):
    """
    Factory method that returns an instance of the Renderer class
    """
    return Renderer(message)
```

In CloudWatch, I see I'm getting this error: `module initialization error. Apps aren't loaded yet.`

I understand that Django is not available for the Lambda function, right? How can I fix this? How can I make the rest of the project available to the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two libraries that Lambda supports out of the box are the standard library and boto3.

There are several ways to install external Python libraries for use in Lambda. I recommend uploading them as a Lambda layer. This is a good guide: https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e